# Ajax load content, jquery effects not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, effects

I'm loading content with ajax, after it loads the content to a `#content` div, the effects that I put on my `main.js` doesn't work over the loaded content. for example this one doesn't works:

```
/* Artworks Hide/show text */
$(".item").hover(function() {
  //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
  $(this).find(".art_title").fadeIn(200);
}, 
function () {
  //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
  $(this).find(".art_title").fadeOut(200);
});
```

When I test the effect over the page without the content being loaded with ajax it works well. So the problem it's that is loaded via that way.

How can I fix it?

I'm using two files: `loader.js` to load the contents and the `main.js` which has the effects

Comment: The reason is obvious, the javascript code never executes at all. See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling the JavaScript code after the new content is loaded with the Ajax call.

When you call `$(".item").hover` it adds it to the elements that EXIST at that moment in time. It does not find elements that exist after it is called.

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you can use on and attach it to the body and it should start working. In 1.8, hover is deprecated so you should attach the mouse events separately.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".item", function() {
    $(this).find(".art_title").stop().fadeIn(200);
}).on("mouseleave", ".item", function () {
    $(this).find(".art_title").stop().fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: it works for the question, but the hover does something strange, it hovers over the other items..(?) im using 1.8, it's because of that? how can i fix it to the 1.8?

Answer (score 2):

Because you are injecting some new content to the DOM and it is not aware about the hover functionality you defined.

Solution : use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("mouseover",".item",function(){
      $(this).find(".art_title").fadeIn(200);
   });
   $(document).on("mouseleave",".item",function(){
      $(this).find(".art_title").fadeOut(200);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you attaching these events on the load complete callback?

```
$("#content")
    .load("remote_content.htm", function () {
        $(".item").hover(function () {
            //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
            $(this).find(".art_title").fadeIn(200);
        }, function () {
            //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
            $(this).find(".art_title").fadeOut(200);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because what your code does is, it is attaching these scripts to events. However, the code will not execute by itself. You need attach it.

Try doing this, Encapsulate the entire code in a function. Once you get response from ajax, put the content in div and at the same time, call the javascript function in which you have encapsulated the entire javascript code. This will cause the code to bind to event.

Now you should be able to see the events.